# How to halt further execution of a script in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to restrict my study to a certain date range, and instead of saying:

```
if (inDateRange)
    plot(...)
```

... I really want to say:

```
if (not inDateRange)
    return
```

Or something equivalent to `return` which causes the execution of the script to just terminate for this candle.  Surprisingly, I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Is it possible in Pine Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot interrupt the execution of the script, but you can hide it

`plot( inDateRange ? your_plot : na )`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for interrupting a strategy.